# Ng Recaptcha - Dynamically loading value inside Angular NgModule for userValue in providers

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using ng-recaptcha (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-recaptcha) to add reCaptcha in my angular 5 application.
I want to load the website key from back end service. I need to provide the key in the NgModule provider session so i can use the key dynamically.

```
providers: [{
        provide: RECAPTCHA_SETTINGS,
        useValue: { siteKey: someVariable}
    }]
```

I need to assign a site key to the variable by calling service.

The code is used in the ui is

```
<re-captcha formControlName="recaptcha" (resolved)="resolved($event)" siteKey="reCaptchakey"></re-captcha>
```